# Memory Address showing? C++

Tags: c++, memory-management

Not really sure what's going on here, I'm using Clion as my IDE which I don't believe has anything to do with this but I figured I'd add that information. My confusion comes from a function that I wrote

```
int Arry()
{

int Mynumbers [5] = {10};

    std::cout << Mynumbers;
}
```

something simple. It should be assigning 5 integers the value of 10. But when I print out Mynumbers I am shown the memory address. Why is this happening, I thought that was what calling pointers was for. Thank you for your time.

Sincerely, 
Nicholas

Comment: `<<` is an operator function, `Mynumbers` will decay to a pointer when passed to it.

Comment: `It should be assigning 5 integers the value of 10` No, it shouldn't. Just the first one, the rest are 0. `But when I print out Mynumbers I am shown the memory address` You 're printing a pointer.

Comment: All an array functions as is just a pointer to the memory address of the first element it contains, that's what you are seeing.

Comment: Thank you guys for the quick response. It's all pretty new to me, hopefully this wasn't an annoying question.

Answer (score 4):

It is a bit complicated, and there are a few issues at play:

1. `std::cout` (actually, `std::ostream`, of which `std::cout` is an instance, does not have an overload of `operator<<` that understands plain arrays. It does have overloads that understand pointers.
2. In C++ (and C) an array name can be used as an expression in a place where a pointer is needed. When there is no better option, the array name will *decay* to a pointer. That is what makes the following legal: `int a[10] = {}; int* p = a;`.
3. The overload that takes a pointer prints it as a hexadecimal address, unless the pointer is of type `char*` or `const char*` (or `wchar` versions), in which case it treats it as a null terminated string.

This is what is happening here: because there isn't an `operator<<` overload that matches the array, it decays to the overload taking a pointer. And as it isn't a character type pointer, you see the hexadecimal address. You are seeing the equivalent of `cout << &MyNumbers[0];`.

Comment: WOw. Just like a lot of the responses I'm getting here, it's amazing. Everyone here really wants to explain these questions to the best of their ability and it's really quite amazing. This is my first question I've ever posted so it's a little overwhelming for right now, as a lot of this information I have been trying to learn myself with nobodies help sense nobody lives around me who codes. So I think I'll be here more often. I've learned more just asking a question than I have with hours of searching. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

Some notes:

```
void Arry()                     // use void if nothing is being returned 
{
    int Mynumbers[5] = {10};    // first element is 10, the rest are 0
    //std::cout << Mynumbers;   // will print the first address because the array decays to a pointer which is then printed
    for (auto i : Mynumbers)    // range-for takes note of the size of the array (no decay)
        std::cout << i << '\t';
}
```

Comment: As I searched around about the use of Auto, as I see you have used here. Why did you use it, seems like it was used in C but not many people use it in C++. The way you used it makes me think that their are ways that it can be used to lessen the work load.

Comment: @Learning The [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/auto) keyword has been re-purposed and now performs a different function. The [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) is also a new construct.

Comment: oh woe. That's awesome. @rex Thank you for letting me know. Cause It seems like I really awesome implementation that I don't know how to use yet XD

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you can think of an array as a pointer to a memory address (this isn't strictly true, and others can explain the subtle differences). When you are calling `cout` on your array name, you are asking for it's contents: the memory address.

If you wish to see what's in the array, you can use a simple for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  std::cout << Mynumbers[i] << " ";
```

Comment: This showed me the info that I was looking for at first. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: The idea behind an Array being a pointer is confusing. But I will try to dive more into understand that.

Answer (score 0):

The value of Mynumbers is in fact the adress of the first element in the array.

try the following:

```
for(int i=0; i<5;i++) {
    cout << Mynumbers[i];
}
```

Comment: An array is not an address. Arrays *decay to* pointers, but they aren’t the same thing.

Comment: "The value of Mynumbers is in fact the adress of the first element in the array.", so... why does `sizeof(Mynumbers)` evaluate to `sizeof(Mynumbers[0])*5` if the value of `Mynumbers` is an address?

Comment: @Geoff `sizeof` performs a compile time operation.

Comment: @Geoff, print Mynumbers and print &Mynumbers[0] and you'll see that the values are equal

Comment: @Unh0lys0da That is only because the tool you use to "print" doesn't have an overload for reference to array, so forces the decay to pointer.

Comment: @Unh0lys0da No, in C++ references are a different thing entirely. You can have function parameters that are references to an array, in which case passing an array doesn't require decay to pointer.

Comment: @juanchopanza Only when passing in a function, which is not what I meant.

Comment: `cout << whatever` is a function call (operator overloads being functions with funny call syntax.)

Comment: Oh yes I meant to use printf, and using printf, you will still find that Mynumbers == &Mynumbers[0]

Comment: @Unh0lys0da So... `printf` is not a function?